# PHP get array key for lowest array value

Tags: php

Using PHP, I am creating an array that contains multiple keys:

```
$loadAverage[$server] = $output["now"];
```

I am then checking the item with the lowest value

```
echo min($loadAverage);
```

but i need to get the key of the array not the value (so the `$server` part i need)

the above is returning the value and not the key of the PHP array

Comment: use an array_search() for that minimum value, which will return the key

Answer (score 1):

```
echo min(array_keys($loadAverage));
```

Comment: this is returning a number - it returns 0 which is the first array item

Comment: Now the question is if OP wants the lowest key or the lowest value and the key from the value

Comment: i want the lowest value and i need the key to be returned

Comment: @Charles There you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28953427/php-get-array-key-for-lowest-array-value#comment46160467_28953427

Comment: @Rizier123 you are directing him to his own question?

Comment: @RST No, click on the link an you see it

Comment: @Rizier123 Yep, it reloads the page

Comment: @RST It's the comment under OPs question

Answer (score 1):

```
$lowest_key = array_keys($loadAverage, min($loadAverage));
echo $lowest_key[0];
```

By supplying a search element you only get the key of that value.

Comment: this is returning Array

Comment: the value is in the array

Answer (score 0):

```
echo array_search(min($loadAverage), $loadAverage);
```